# Где можно поподробнее почитать про конструкцию replaceAll?

Tags: java, строки

```
public static String autocorrect(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(u|you+)\\b", "your sister");
}
```

Где можно поподробнее почитать про эту конструкцию `replaceAll`?

Comment: если вы про метод String.replaceAll - то тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Например, [тут](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp).

Comment: Видимо, вся "магия" кроется в регулярных выражениях, а не в самом методе. Гуглите их

Answer (score 4):

Порой кажется, что люди совсем разучились гуглить, читайте официальную документацию, ну и например здесь можно посмотреть: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm